# trying to install node and angular but it's not working!

Tags: release-juno

I'm trying to install node and angular on my machine but every time I do I get the error below. if someone could help I'd be really great.

```
rr:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tigerite/kernel/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tigerite/kernel/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Error executing command, exiting
```

Comment: Generally I would not recommend to use the official packages for installing Node.js as they are quite outdated. For me [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) worked better.

Answer (score 1):

I pretty much got it to work following this guide:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-18-04

That message, however, doesn't really relate to npm or node.js. Did that happen on a clean elementary installation, or did you try to manually add certain package repositories (most notably, in this case, the tigerite kernel PPA)?